# Authenticating user with Facebook using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, facebook, oauth, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security 3.0.x and I'd like my users to authenticate using OpenId and Facebook. Currently I've got the OpenId-part working, but I'm confused about how users can login with Facebook. I've read about the [OAuth](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/oauth2.html) for Spring security, but as fas as I undestand, it is only good for accessing resources. The example applications authenticate with username and password.

So my question is, how do I authenticate users with Facebook using Spring security?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Security doesn't address this (as of yet).   Check out [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) which is designed to connect your app to Facebook, Twitter, etc.   Also check out [this blog post](http://blog.trickl.com/?tag=spring-social), where they have integrated Spring Social and Spring Security.

Comment: Could you please update the broken link of the blog thanks

Answer (score 5):

I have created a new project called [spring-security-social for Facebook](http://code.google.com/p/spring-security-social/), which provides an authentication filter based on [spring-security-oauth](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/). As opposed to spring-security-facebook, it is actively maintained by [acoveo software development](http://www.acoveo.com) and builts upon the new spring-security-oauth release.

Comment: Hey that's great! One problem with the blog post in ericacm's answer is that the Spring Social API had changed and it was kind of throwaway code so I had to build my solution from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use https://github.com/pac4j/spring-security-pac4j which supports OAuth (Facebook, Twitter, Google...), CAS, SAML, OpenID (Connect) and GAE. See the demo: https://github.com/pac4j/spring-security-pac4j-demo

Comment: is there a spring security java config example somewhere? I found this but I don't think it is configured correctly https://github.com/pawelantczak/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/src/main/java/org/antczak/oauth/SecurityConfig.java . The ClientAuthenticationEntryPoint are never used in the config.

Comment: I didn't know about this example, but it looks good. Otherwise, there was this example in the README: https://github.com/pac4j/spring-security-pac4j/tree/1.3.x#java-config-sample