# How to provide facebook, twitter, linkedin and live login using SpringSecurity?

Tags: java, facebook, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

My question is related to following Stackoverflow questions already present here... I am asking this question just to be more specific and get the latest suggestions, excuse me if you find it a duplicate question ..
[Facebook Connect question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942984/spring-security-integrate-with-facebook-connect) and [LogIn using Spring Security Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012203/how-to-login-in-website-using-facebook-id)

currently I am working on a task which requires me to deal with open login support. I have used Spring Security 3.0.5 in this application. Successfully provided authentication support to a set of open Id providers (gmail,yahoo,myopenid,openid,aol, wordpress, blogger, livejournal etc. ). Now next I want to provide support for four big names facebook, twitter, linkedin and live(msn).

In a separate demo application I have romanced with Spring Social to provide facebook login and got kind of success there. Similar steps can be used for linked and twitter login. But Since I am handling the login using Spring Security in original project **I want to achieve the facebook, twitter, linkedin and live login also using spring security only. and unfortunately not getting much information regarding this.**

Any tutorial or source regarding this will be helpful...

edit 1:
just came across [Spring Security Social](http://code.google.com/p/spring-security-social/)... that is also not a desirable solution in its present state...

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773233/authenticating-user-with-facebook-using-spring-security) might help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Security doesn't address this (as of yet).   [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) which you saw is designed to connect your app to Facebook, Twitter, etc.

Check out [this blog post](http://blog.trickl.com/?tag=spring-social), where they have integrated Spring Social and Spring Security.

EDIT: Work is being done on adding an official integration between the two - check [this fork](https://github.com/molindo/spring-social/tree/security/spring-social-security/src/main/java/org/springframework/social) of the Spring Social project on Github.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Spring Security with OpenID and OAuth](http://www.yuanhengdesigns.com/blog/?p=72).

Answer (score 0):

This is solution:
[socialsignin spring security](https://github.com/socialsignin/spring-social-security).
It is based on [spring-social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) and work perfect.